# I made a very basic calculator and it doesn't run

Tags: python, python-2.7, calculator

I made a very basic calculator in Python 2.7.

It worked fine.

Then I wrapped it in a function called `start` so the program doesn't end after each calculation and it stopped working.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
def start():
    user_function = raw_input('type "sub" to subtract, "add" to add, "div" to divide or "mul" to multiply: ') 
    print "You selected " + user_function 
    if user_function == "add":
       # Lots more logic in here.
       # Removed because it is irrelevant to the question.
    else:
        print "you did not provide a valid function" 
    start()
```

Comment: You appear to have `start()` indented inside of `def start():`. Therefore, you are never really calling your function. The `start()` at the end need not to be indented

Comment: Is there any reason why you have gone for the old 2.7 release?  If you are learning Python then it makes sense to go for Python 3 (current release is 3.5).

Comment: This is not a 'debug my code for free' service!

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen your call to your start function? Its indentation is wrong, it should have the same level of indentation as your `def start():` line.

```
def start():
   # your code here
   start() # indentation incorrect
start() # correct indentation
```

Comment: Why incorrect ? if start function got break condition ! This method a sample `loop` function.  You need create a class for loop function otherwise recursive limit will be break your function. This method not wrong ! I am talking about your code not question code.... :D

Answer (score -2):

It is because you wrote a function but did not call it outside the function. Also, If you just want to run it in this python file, you can add

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

or just simply call`start()`outside and below the start function.